# SummerNote ContentEditable Attribute Make False

Tags: javascript, jquery, summernote

I am trying to contenteditable attribute of [summernote](http://summernote.org/) html editor  pluging making false on  page loading , but it doesnt affect.

Here My JS Code:

```
<script>
    $(function(){
     $('div#son_durum').children('.note-editor')
                       .children('.note-editing-area')
                       .children('.note-editable')
                       .attr('contenteditable',false);
    });
</script>
```

What Can I Do Achive This?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why did you try to set `contenteditable` as `false`? Just leave it and don't initiate summernote on `div#son_durum` when your page is loading.

Or, do you want to toggle enable/disable state of summernote? A similar issue was already reported. See https://github.com/summernote/summernote/issues/1109

Answer (score 0):

Using v0.8.2.
Here's my solution, though it's not perfect, especially if the developers change the html and or class names, but it works for what I need.

My MVC application has many summernote controls being dynamically added to a page, and each has an ID assigned to it.  Some controls only display the image (upload) button, while others only display the text style buttons.  For my image-only summernote controls I don't want the user to have the ability to type text, so I have to only disable the text-entry/image panel, not the whole control.  This way I still allow the buttons to be used.

**Here is my solution, and this works!** Make sure this fires after the summernote control initialization.

```
var container = $('#summernote2').nextAll('div.note-editor:first').find('.panel-body');        
            if ($(container).length)        
            {            
                $(container).prop('contenteditable', 'false');                                
            }
```

**What's Happening?**

1. Within my specific summernote control (id = summernote2), I locate the first div immediately below it with the specific class ('note-editor').  All of these are added dynamically to the page when the control is initialized. See the image below:[image: summernote HTML image]
2. Then, using FIND, continue to work down the tree looking for the class 'panel-body', which is where the text is actually placed, highlighted in the image above.
3. Assuming I find it, then I change the *contenteditable* property to false.  BAM!

There is probably more chaining that could be done, and perhaps more efficient methods but this works pretty neatly.

**Why this way?**
Because I have multiple controls on the page, and nothing directly linking my ID'd summernote DIV to all those other DIVs that are created as part of the initialization, I thought this was a good solution.  Otherwise, how could I guarantee getting the correct panel-body class?

Good luck and let me know what you think!  If this answers your question sufficiently, remember to check it as answered!

In a perfect world you'd think the developers would have made it easier.  This *should* be all it takes, but no it doesn't work...:

```
$('#summernote2').summernote('contenteditable','false');
```